# Cordova platform add android error (Construct 2)

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, construct-2

apk file with a construct two projects exported via Cordova

I open cmd then I reach to my folder with the exported project and when I try to add android using cmd - "cordova platform add android"

I get this:

> 'Discovered plugin "cordova-custom-config" in config.xml. Adding it to
>   the project Failed to restore plugin "cordova-custom-config" from
>   config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Failed to
>   fetch plugin cordova-custom-config via registry. Probably this is
>   either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect. Check your
>   connection and plugin name/version/URL. Error: cmd: Command failed
>   with exit code 1 Error output: npm ERR! code ENOGIT npm ERR! No git
>   binary found in $PATH npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed using git. npm ERR!
>   Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.'

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

do this: cordova platform rm android && cordova platform add android